# OWIN WebApp.Start Does not fire browser

Tags: asp.net, owin

I am new to `Owin` and `Katana`. I begin to learn `OWIN` by Scott Allen articles in [OdeToCode](http://odetocode.com/). Currently I am in first attemp to run simple project as Scott described in [Getting Started With OWIN, Katana, and VS2013](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2013/07/09/getting-started-with-owin-katana-and-vs2013.aspx). I followed his description step by step and Insalled 4 nugget and I [here](http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/getting-started-with-owin-and-katana) for assurance. Anyway, When I run Console application, console will appears but browser does not fires!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sorry for simple an newbie question, I found my answer:

I just paste "localhost:8080" in my browser an pressed enter. It works fine.